# In Whitehead&Russell's PM's ✳210, how can the product of $\lambda$ be not a member of $\lambda$?

Tags: logic, math-history, foundations

Take ✳210.23 for example:

Assuming $\kappa$ is a classes of classes such that, of any two, one is contained in the other, *i.e.* $\alpha, \beta \in \kappa .\supset_{\alpha, \beta} : \alpha \subset \beta . \vee . \beta \subset \alpha  $

✳210.23 $\vdash:Hp✳210.2. \lambda \subset \kappa. p‘\lambda\in \kappa-\lambda.\supset. p‘\lambda=prec_Q‘\lambda=tl_Q‘\lambda$

I wonder, in the hypothesis, if the product of $\lambda$ can ever NOT be a member of $\lambda$.
In other words, can this ever happen? $\lambda \subset \kappa.p‘\lambda\in \kappa-\lambda$.

If you can come up with a concrete example, please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See page 592, vol.II :

> if $\lambda$ is any sub-class of $\kappa$, the logical product $p‘\lambda$ is the minimum of $\lambda$ if it is a member of $\lambda$, and the lower limit of $\lambda$ if it is a member of $\kappa$ but not of $\lambda$.

**SECTION B** deals with *sections* (sic !) and the Dedekindian treatment of the continuum.

I think that the discussion is related to the [Completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) property of the *real* line.

Consider as $\kappa$ the set $\mathbb R$ of *real* numbers, with the usual ordering, and consider as $\lambda$ the set $\{ r \in \mathbb Q^+ | 2 \le r^2 \}$.

I.e. $\lambda$ is the set of positive *rational* numbers whose square is greater-or-equal than two; clearly, the *lower limit* of $\lambda$ is $\sqrt 2$, which is **not** rational.

Thus, it is a member of $\kappa$ but not of $\lambda$, and so it is not the *minimum* of $\lambda$.

If instead we consider $\lambda' = \{ r \in \mathbb R^+ | 2 \le r^2 \}$ [i.e. the set of positive *real* numbers whose square is greater-or-equal than two], we have that $\sqrt 2$ is the *minimum* of $\lambda'$, because - being a real - it is a member of $\lambda'$.

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro. That explained the difference between minimum and lower limit. If I'm not mistaken, the $p$ in $p‘\lambda$ is the product defined in 40.01, _i.e._$p‘\lambda =\hat{x}\{ \alpha \in \lambda .\supset. x\in \alpha \}$. At this point (chapt. 210), PM hasn't shown how to relate real numbers to sets yet.

Comment: If everyone either contains or is contained by someone else in the set, then the product of the set must be one of its members. How could it happen otherwise?

Comment: It seems to me that the "product" is the *intersection* of the class $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a class of classes; thus, in modern terms, $x \in p‘\lambda \equiv \forall \alpha(\alpha \in \lambda \rightarrow x \in \alpha)$

Comment: Our definitions totally agree. So, can it ever happen that $p‘\lambda$ is not a member of $\lambda$?

Comment: When $\lambda$ is a sub-set of $\kappa$ defined above.

Comment: OK. I saw the nested internals from your link. That's an example.

Comment: In general, it is not true that $p‘λ \in λ$. Consider $\lambda = \{ \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \}$; $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are the only members of $\lambda$. Assume now that $\alpha_1 = \{ 1,2 \}, \alpha_2 = \{ 2,3 \}$. Clearly, the *intersection* $\alpha_1 \cap \alpha_2 = \{ 2 \}$, because $2$ is the only object which is both memeber of $\alpha_1$ and of $\alpha_2$. Thus, $p‘λ = \{ 2 \}$ but $p‘λ \ne \alpha_1$ and $p‘λ \ne \alpha_2$. Of course, $p‘λ \subset \alpha_i$; we have not to forget the difference between *membership* ($\in$) and *inclusion* ($\subset$).

Comment: It'll be nice if we have a name for $κ$. $κ$ as mentioned above is a class of classes, of any two, one is contained in the other. I'd like to call it telescopic class in the sense of telescopic poles. Any sub-class of a telescopic class, say λ, is also a telescopic class. If λ is finite, then both the sum and product of λ are also members of λ. When λ is infinite, this is not guaranteed, and whether or not it is the case needs to be in the hypothesis. The nested intervals in your link is a good example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Nested_intervals_theorem